# How to sequentially pass a set of 1D arrays to a function, in C(preferred)/C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, memory

I have a set of 1D arrays of varying sizes, e.g.:

```
P1 [] = {0,2,5,6,9,8,7,55,7,4,1} 
P2 [] = {11,22,55,5,8,7,4,65,87,7,88,9,8,77,4,5,6,33,2,1,44,5,8,55} 
P3 [] = {0} 
//...
//...
Pn [] = { "","","","",...."",""}
```

I want to sequentially pass these arrays to a function, say -
function (`Pi`) ,  where I varies from `1` to `n`.
How can I do this?
All the 1D arrays are known before run-time. Memory needs to be optimized and hence using a 2d array would be less than efficient.

Comment: did you tried 2D array?

Comment: How do it know the size of the array doing is on the side of the function?

Comment: If your title says _"in C"_, why is it tagged C++?

Comment: @keyser , Sorry, I'll fix (edit) that. C or C++ would do , although c would be preferred.

Comment: @AerofoilKite - Yes, but that would mean declaring a single 2d array of size P[l][m], where 'm' would be the number of elements contained by the largest single dimensional array. Hence I'l be wasting memory(?).

Comment: If your arrays are the way they are shown then you can loop as shown by alk in his answer else you can have a 2D array and just pass the row address in each loop

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , if you meant to ask how the function ascertains the number of elements in each 1D array (Pi), then, :- it is known before run time and hence can be either passed to the function as a separate variable , or estimated using the 'sizeof'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Store all those array's 1st element's addresses (i.e, pointers to first elements of arrays) in another array, defining an "*array of pointers*", called `pv`:

```
void * pv[] =
{
  P1, P2, P3, ..., Pn, NULL
};
```

then loop over this array's elements.

```
size_t i = 0;
while (NULL != pv[i])
{
  function(pv[i]);
  ++i;
}
```

However be aware, you'll lose the size of the arrays passed down to `function`.

The following approach WILL NOT work:

```
void function(void * p)
{
  size_t s = sizeof p;
  ...
```

`s` would be the size of a pointer, that is typically 4 or 8 depending on your platfrom.

Although merely hitting C's limits trying to get around this and stay with more or less roboust code the following is possible:

```
enum Type
{
  TypeInt,
  TypeCharPtr,
  ...
};

struct Array_Descriptor
{
  size_t s;
  void * p;
  enum Type t;
};

int P1 [] = {0,2,5,6,9,8,7,55,7,4,1};
int P2 [] = {11,22,55,5,8,7,4,65,87,7,88,9,8,77,4,5,6,33,2,1,44,5,8,55};
int P3 [] = {0};
...
char * Pn [] = { "","","","",...."",""};

struct Array_Descriptor ads[] =
{
  {sizeof P1/sizeof *P1, P1, TypeInt},
  {sizeof P2/sizeof *P2, P2, TypeInt},
  {sizeof P3/sizeof *P3, P3, TypeInt},
  ...
  {sizeof Pn/sizeof *Pn, Pn, TypeCharPtr},
};

...

size_t s = sizeof ads/sizeof *ads;
for (size_t i = 0; ; i < s; ++i)
{
  function(ads + i);
}
```

The defintion of `function` would be changed to:

```
void function(struct Array_Descriptor * pad);
```

Data, number of elements and type can be access via

```
void function(struct Array_Descriptor * pad)
{
  void * p = pad->p;
  size_t s = pad->s;
  enum Type = pad->t;
```

Comment: But as I understand, he should be able to pass sizes too

Comment: The elements of `pv` aren't pointers to arrays. Sry. @haccks. They would have been if I'd coded `void * pv[] = {&P1, &P2, ...`.

Comment: @alk; Now it is fine.

Comment: OK. Now I am giving up :). Is there any difference in these two syntax which I am missing here? @alk.

Comment: You could agree the compromise?-) @haccks I felt your "*called*" was referring to the wrong thing.

Comment: Oh! That wording was the source of confusion. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the sample for passing multiple arrays to the function. There can be better methods than this. However, I think it would suffice to provide direction.

```
struct Aggregate
{
    void* ptr_array;
    size_t size;
};

void fun(Aggregate *aggr, size_t size)
{
        double *ptr = static_cast<double*>(aggr[1].ptr_array);
        int length = aggr[1].size;
        for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
            cout << *(ptr+i) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
    double arr1[] = {1.0, 2.0};

    Aggregate *aggr = new Aggregate[2];   <<< You could remove this new if you know how many
    aggr[0].ptr_array = arr;              <<< arrays you are going to pass to fun
    aggr[0].size = 4;
    aggr[1].ptr_array = arr1;
    aggr[1].size = 2;

    fun(aggr, 2);

    delete [] aggr;         
}
```

Comment: I'd suspect it was downvoted because you proposed `new`, whereas the OP asks for memory optimization. (not the downvoter)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah , I could replace that with compile time constant. But I don't know details for his needs so left it open...

Answer (score 1):

```
void *pp[] = { P1, P2, P3, ..., PN };

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(pp)/sizeof(pp[0]); i++)
    function(pp[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With C++11 and variadic template, you may do something like

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void Function(const T (&a)[N])
{
    // Your implementation
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void Function(const T& t, const Ts&... args)
{
    Function(t);
    Function(args...);
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/lvBbbG)